# Coding4Fun InputPrompt disable show copy

Tags: windows-phone-8

i use a InputPrompt of Coding4Fun Toolkit.
I have this problem: appears a copy to clipboard. It is possible

this is a image example
[image]

it is possibile not show button copy?
thank you

Comment: Coding4Fun is a custom Toolkit. InputPrompt control force a SelectAll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

responded on the coding4fun discussion.  a lot depends on what exactly you're trying to accomplish here.  The control gets focus for the input text and I think the default behavior is to highlight everything.  https://coding4fun.codeplex.com/discussions/539010#post1222803